# I don't understand Double linked list implementation from CTCI in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am going through CTCI book and I really cannot wrap my head around the `last` property of DoubleLinkedList(DLL) implementation from the author. No matter how I try to initialise the DLL it's always `null` when I ask for that property.

As far as I understand the `last` property is not a class variable(no **static** keyword) so each Node object will have its own `last` element. I would expect the DLL, to have a pointer to the `last` fixed at all times(point to the last Node in the entire DLL), is that incorrect?

Moreover, I was thinking about implementing `head` property into that implementation, and doing a similar thing with updating it in `setPrevious` function. I would update the head if `setPrevious` was called on the head. Is that stupid, why wouldn't she implement that logic?

This is the code from the book and my tries to get some output from the `last` property

```java
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    public LinkedListNode prev;
    public LinkedListNode last;
    public int data;
    public LinkedListNode(int d, LinkedListNode n, LinkedListNode p) {
        data = d;
        setNext(n);
        setPrevious(p);
    }
    
    public LinkedListNode(int d) {
        data = d;
    }   
    
    public LinkedListNode() { }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (this == last) {
            last = n;
        }
        if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
            n.setPrevious(this);
        }
    }
    
    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode p) {
        prev = p;
        if (p != null && p.next != this) {
            p.setNext(this);
        }
    }   
    
    public String printForward() {
        if (next != null) {
            return data + "->" + next.printForward();
        } else {
            return ((Integer) data).toString();
        }
    }
    
    public LinkedListNode clone() {
        LinkedListNode next2 = null;
        if (next != null) {
            next2 = next.clone();
        }
        LinkedListNode head2 = new LinkedListNode(data, next2, null);
        return head2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListNode ll = new LinkedListNode(1);
        ll.setNext(new LinkedListNode(2));

        System.out.println(ll.last);
        System.out.println(ll.next.last);

        LinkedListNode firstNode = new LinkedListNode(1);
        LinkedListNode thirdNode = new LinkedListNode(3);

        LinkedListNode ll2 = new LinkedListNode(1, thirdNode, firstNode);
        System.out.println(firstNode.last);
        System.out.println(ll2.last);
        System.out.println(thirdNode.last);
        
    }
}
```

```
> null
> null
> null
> null
> null
```

Comment: If the `last` property was `static` then you could only have 1 DLL in your code as every node would point to the same `last` node. Better would be to have a `LinkedList` class that holds fields and methods that apply to the entire structure (such as `last`) rather than having them in the node class.

Comment: Yeah that does make sense. Thanks

Comment: Either you made a transcription error or the code from the book has an error. There's no way that `last` can ever be anything but `null`.

Comment: This is copied from the book, if you look at the edits I also uploaded previously my "renamed" version of the code and picture from and the book but then decided to just upload code from the book. https://i.stack.imgur.com/miCoQ.jpg Anyhow thanks for taking your time to look at it